# Upcoming Event: How do I sort database by custom date field, but ignore past dates?

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, loop, query

I am using an events plugin and struggling to get my database query to be perfect.  The query is on the event-single.php template. What I need the query to do:

- Query the "events" custom post type for upcoming events
- Sort by `_event_start_date` meta_key to show earliest date (nearest event)
- Not display PAST events
- If "current event", show next nearest event

Here's my current $args.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post__not_in' => array($donotrepeat),
    "post_type" => 'event',
    'meta_key' => '_event_start_date', // name of custom field
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    "order" => 'ASC',
    "posts_per_page" => 1
   );
?>
```

Defining `$donotrepeat` earlier

```
$donotrepeat = get_the_ID();
```

So far, the query successfully

- Queries custom post type
- Ignores the "current" event
- Sorts by earliest date.

I cannot figure out how to ignore 'past' dates though.  There is another meta key 'scope' created by this plugin that contains values like 'past' and 'future' - so that could be promising.

I've tried using meta_query to sort through the past date issue, but I just can't seem to get it to work.  I think this is probably the way to go, but I'm open to other ideas.  I'm sure this isn't THAT difficult... can anyone help?

Comment: How is the date stored? YYYY-MM-DD? Timestamp?

Comment: It's YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close, but I wouldn't be distracted by the 'scope' meta key. The following is untested.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post__not_in' => array($donotrepeat),
    "post_type" => 'event',
    'meta_key' => '_event_start_date', // name of custom field
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    "order" => 'ASC',
    "posts_per_page" => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_event_start_date',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    ),
);
?>
```

The meta_key is only present for ordering - meta_query controls the actual selection.

Note that I left your posts_per_page as is, even though it will limit the selection to one record.

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly!  I knew meta_query was the answer, just missed on the date format.  Thanks!

Comment: `type => DATE` is the magic. Not found in so many websites. Thanks @vancoder